# Sql Server 2008 Backup and Restore

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a production critical database which is in Simple Recover Model Currently. We take a Full Backup Every night at 2:30AM. Now I have to change the recovery model back to full. I have to design the backup and restore strategy to include the Differential and Transaction log backups. My manager wants a full backup every night, diff backup every 6 hours and tlog backups every 15 min. So what are steps should i take to achieve the above scenarios. Please help, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How big is the database? How large are the logs generated daily? What backup product are you using?

Comment: Its about 200GB. We are using 2008 maintenance plan to do the full back up every night. Now i have to change back to Full Recovery model.

Comment: The how and when of backing up the database should be driven by the needs of the business. Until you determine those I don't see how you can put an effective plan that meets those needs in place.

Answer (score 0):

Backup and recovery operations in SQL Server can be a rather daunting task especially when dealing with large databases and multiple backups.  Your overall environment plays a pretty big factor in your strategy as well.  Do you only have a single database server?  Are you running in a cluster?  Using mirroring?  Log shipping?  Are off-site data centers available?  What kind of bandwidth is available?  Do you have SAN storage available?

If up-time is critical and you cannot deal with a production outage then something like a failover cluster or database mirroring may be what you need.  If disaster recovery is your primary goal, then something like log shipping may be more appropriate.  If both are important, you might need a hybrid combination of (for example) a failover cluster in a primary data center combined with log shipping to a standby server at an alternate location.

Here are a few resources you may want to have a look at:

- [Backing Up and Restoring Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187048.aspx)
- [High Availability Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190202.aspx)
- [Failover Clustering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189134.aspx)
- [Database Mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934127.aspx)
- [Log Shipping Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187103.aspx)

There are quite a few branches off of each of the above links which should help provide some point of reference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you asked the same question yesterday:  [Sql Server 2008 Backup and Restore](https://serverfault.com/questions/279730/sql-server-2008-backup-and-restore/279886#279886)

Have a look at the answer I gave for some additional resources you can read about backup and recovery operations as well as some high availability options.

Comment: Sorry i did not see your answer yesterday. We have Peer to Peer Replication for High Availability.