# Sql Server 2008 Backup and Restore

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a Critical Production Database for sql server 2008 which is in Simple Recovery Model Currently. I have to change the Recovery Model back to Full. I have to develop a Strategy to take Full, Differential and Transactional Log Backups. So my questions is: What is the First Step should i take after i change the Recovery Model to Full?  How do i set up the Diff Backups and Transactional Backups? What are the Interval time should i take for each backup. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql Server 2008 Backup and Restore](http://serverfault.com/questions/279730/sql-server-2008-backup-and-restore)